# C# Cannot Cast Calculated Column From SQL Server SELECT

Tags: c#, casting

I cannot seem to figure out a way to cast a calculated column from a SQL Server 2012 `SELECT` statement. I'm calculating a simple value called Yield that is basically a percentage.

```
SELECT 
    TotalUnique, 
    TotalFail, 
    ISNULL(((TotalUnique - NullIf(TotalFail, 0)) / CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 2), TotalUnique) * 100), 100) AS Yield 
FROM 
    Products
```

For the `Yield` column how would I retrieve this with a reader? I keep getting the error message

> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

on the line:

```
DBYield = (float)reader["Yield"]
```

I've looked all day for something that would provide me a clue but have had no luck.

```
int DBTotalUnique = 0;
int DBTotalFailed = 0;
float DBYield = 00.0f;

while (reader.Read())
{
     DBTotalUnique = (int)reader["TotalUnique"];
     DBTotalFailed = (int)reader["TotalFail"];
     DBYield = (float)reader["Yield"]
}
```

Could someone please give me a hint?

Comment: Have you tried doing the casting on the database side as well? Returning known types would be better

Comment: It's probably a double because of `Numeric(38, 2)`.

Comment: @Amy good call on the numeric cast, but numerics map to decimals.

Comment: @LewsTherin ah, you're right.  I've been bested by the Kinslayer. What an honor.

Answer (score 3):

`Numeric` in TSQL is equivalent to `Decimal` in .NET (see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-types-net-framework/mapping-clr-parameter-data?view=sql-server-2017) for the data type mappings from TSQL to .NET).

Try casting to a `decimal`.